# Opencart showing product quantity after removing from php file

Tags: php, opencart, categories

I want to hide the product quantity from the left column category menu, eg

```
>  T-Shirt(36)
>             -Polo(10)
```

, I want to remove the quantities within the bracket. For this I have edited the `catalog/controller/product/category.php` file with the following :

```
 $this->data['categories'][] = array(
  //'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
 'name'  => $result['name'],
  'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
 );
```

But the page still showing the quantities ! Where should I edit so that the quantities are hidden ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the file you need to edit is:

```
catalog/controller/module/category.php
```

and it is after (it is in the file twice):

```
if ($setting['count']) {
```

you will simply change it from:

```
'name'        => $category['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')',
```

to:

```
'name'        => $category['name'],
```

However this is also an option in the backend of admin to disable the category counts... under system and then settings and then edit your store and select no to category counts